# Problem running make - Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: make, gcc

Ubunutu 18.04.4 LTS  - 
Linux 5.3.0-28  - 
gcc 7.4.0

I'm trying to run make, and I get the following output

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Makefile:1699: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I tried adding `SHELL := /bin/bash` to the top of the `makefile`.

Then I get the following.

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic/build M=/home/dubsta/Downloads/Archer T9UH(EU&US)_V2_170831_Linux/linux_T9UH  modules'
Makefile:1700: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 1
```

The first few lines of the `Makefile` look like this:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
EXTRA_CFLAGS += $(USER_EXTRA_CFLAGS)
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O1
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O3
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wall
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wextra
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Werror
```

I've double checked that the kernal headers for hte linux version I'm using are installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the directory you’re running this from, `/home/dubsta/Downloads/Archer T9UH(EU&US)_V2_170831_Linux/linux_T9UH  modules`. The kernel Makefiles don’t handle directories containing spaces, and I’m not sure about the parentheses and ampersand either.

To fix this, rename `Archer T9UH(EU&US)_V2_170831_Linux` and `linux_T9UH  modules` to something simpler, with no spaces, and try again (adjusting your command as appropriate).